# Will my HEX file fit in my microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, programming

I have a hex file with a size of 42 kB.  Does the size matter while loading it in a microcontroller?  Can I load 42 kB hex file in a ATMEGA32 chip which has a memory of 32 kB?

Comment: Normally a hex file is compiled for a specific processor and should be used only in that processor.  At least for the uc I have used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `avr-size` to check the real size of your program:

```
[jpc@jpc sepack] avr-size sepack.elf 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   4396       6     277    4679    1247 sepack.elf
[jpc@jpc sepack] avr-size sepack.hex 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      0    4402       0    4402    1132 sepack.hex
```

As you can see it works better with `.elf` files since it can also show you both how much ram you need (`data`+`bss`) and how much flash will be used (`text`+`data`). With the `.hex` file only shows you the second figure (labeling it `data`)

Comment: So whats the size of my hex file ? I get the following details while i check my file..
text - 13858, data - 926, bss - 1043 dec - 15927, hex - 3dd3

Comment: You will need 13858+926=14784 bytes of Flash and 1969 bytes of RAM (+ some space for stack space). I guess that means a part with at least 16kB and 4kB RAM (3 would be enough but that may be hard to find).

Comment: You may have trouble fitting into the RAM of the ATmega32. You should either lower the RAM usage, carefully check stack space usage or switch to a part with 4k RAM.

Answer (score 9):

The hex file generated is often somewhat human-readable and includes checksum data, both of which inflate the size a few times.  I believe that AVRs use the [Intel HEX format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Hex), while other micro toolchains use other formats; e.g. Codewarrior for Freescale HCS08 provides [Motorola S-records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S19_%28file_format%29), which is extremely similar.

If you open the .hex file with a text editor (Notepad), it should look similar to this, though much longer:

```
:10010000214601360121470136007EFE09D2190140
:100110002146017EB7C20001FF5F16002148011988
```

where the various fields are described in the [example on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Hex#Example).  There are only 16 bytes in each of those lines that denote data that will be stored in the micro, the rest is checksum and control data that is just used by the flasher program.

Comment: Hex files also allow for gaps in the data (the first field is the load address). So, potentially, a small non-contiguous hex file could have a large footprint in RAM/flash

Answer (score 3):

Each byte in a hex file takes two hex digits, plus a few characters per record. Your hex file should fit in the device's flash memory.